# Force Run System File Checker (SFC.exe)

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, sfc

```
C:\Windows\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

There is a system repair pending which requires reboot to complete.  Restart
Windows and run sfc again.
```

Is there a way I can force `SFC` to scan again and make the new fixes on reboot?

Probably by deleting some file or something? I removed `C:\Windows\WinSxS\pending.xml` by taking ownerships but it still shows the same message.

Comment: You need to undo the "dirty bit", if that's even possible. Sorry for such vague help, that's all I really know about this matter.

Comment: Why are you against rebooting per the instructions?

Comment: @Ramhound Running a server and few other reasons.

Comment: If you suspect malware on a server you should nuke from orbit.  How is malware getting on a server?

Comment: I have no idea why nothing helps, so I deleted my answer. You should fix your real issue (how can a tool corrupt a system file on a server).